# IE 9 & 10 events not firing (consistently)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js, blur

I am developing a web application. This application due to requirement contains a table with 500+ rows (unpaged). The application is very interactive and so we're using KO behind the scenes.

That said I am noticing that occasionally tabbing on an input text box, does not take you to the nearest text box, instead it takes you to the *first input text box* on the page. When this happens a couple of things also happen:

1. The `blur` event does not trigger.
2. The `focusout` event also does not trigger. I have had to work around the issue by detecting mouse click and fire the events off manually using jQuery.
3. Unobtrusive validation will not work.
4. View model is not bound ie. changes on the input box is not reflected on the KO view model.

The issue is intermittent, I cannot necessarily reproduce it consistently, but it is happening frequently - and considering money is involved in this application I need this to work 100%.

Also testing the same application on Chrome and Firefox works perfectly. No intermittent issue as detected on IE9 and 10. Is there a known browser bug around this issue? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: The tab order is controlled by the `tabIndex` attribute and/or the layout order.  I'm not sure how we could offer much help on the tab order or the missing events without seeing the problem HTML/JS in action.   The most likely cause of a missing event would be a JS error in one of the frameworks you're using which causes the event handler to stop executing before it gets to your code.

Comment: I don't know if I can copy and paste the entire HTML file on a public site. It does not happen nearly enough for me to isolate the offending code. The tabindex are all set to 0. I say 75% of the time, hitting tab will just take the cursor to the nearest input box. However 25% of the time the same textbox when tabbed will trigger the bugs described above. Note I can work around tab out of order, the bigger concern is **events not triggering** when they should and ViewModel not getting updated consistently.

Comment: If it's a public site, you can include a link to the site, with specific instructions for how to reproduce the problem and then copy only any specifically relevant code or HTML into your post.

Comment: @Alwyn you could try to console.log in the framework code to see when an event happens. I don't know about KO but is it possible it silently fails? In that case you might have to set some variable so it'll trace/log more information for you (don't know if this is possible). I guess KO sets listeners on the parent of the textboxes instead setting it on all individual texts. You can dig into the code and console log from the root (where KO gets the event from DOM) and see why it's not being transferred correctly. That is assuming that IE triggers the event.